# Ability to resolve module dependencies dynamically based on version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**Backstory:**

In eclipse, when you have multiple projects open with pom files (and therefore versions), it will automatically use local-references if the versions match one of your listed dependencies.  If they don't match, then it relies on the artifact in the repo. *(this is handy as it allows you to do live-edits/linking on active versions, while having fixed dependencies on unstable project/dependency versions).*

---

---

**Question**

In gradle, there doesn't seem to be a way to say

> I depend on this sub-module, version X

Rather, it seems you are only able to say

> I depend on this sub-module, I don't care which version, I'll take the current/active one.

---

So, is there a better syntax to the regular:

```
compile project(':submodules:submodule1')
```

Perhaps something like?:

```
compile project(':submodules:submodule1:0.1-SNAPSHOT')
```

or

```
compile project('com.mydomain:submodule1:0.1-SNAPSHOT')
```

Comment: How do you do versioning in modules? A module is essentially just a directory on disk with a build file in it. How would you organize versions?

Comment: Well, when a module builds and if that module is maven-enabled, then the build server would push that artifact to the local nexus repository.  That way, that version of that module is available there.  likewise, running an 'install' locally with a given module would also generate the artifact for local-reference.

Comment: So normally, you'd push up your project, and it would hit the build server, and that build server would build and construct all the artifacts recursively within the project, pushing the appropriate versions to the repository.

Comment: It seems that you can make a dependency not to the module but artifact built from this module. So A depends on B. You build it and install locally (1.0-SNAPSHOT version) and locally you make a dependency to this snapshot version. Will that work?

Comment: Somewhat? I've tried that before...it would be nice if it picked up on that dependency during the project assembly/build, but I can always modify the gradle script to enforce a certain task ordering so that it'll resolve.  I just wanted to be sure there wasn't an automatic way to do it, before diving down that path.  I'll play around with it more and see where I end up. :)

Comment: So, after some fiddling, it is only possible to get the build to pass for that submodule install, IFF org.gradle.configureondemand=true, (this is because it needs to make sure it skips all the other modules whose dependency on this particular snapshot would break the build).  This happens because it is not smart enough to know/look-at submodules and realize that they would generate and correspond to the artifact it requires.

Comment: I currently am trying to get it working with flavors, but it is running into a naming collision issue, because the android flavoring doesn't preface submodule task names with the name of the flavor.  Therefore both the maven artifact task and the submodule tasks collide. (eg. task ':app:prepareComTutelatechnologiesTkutilities01SNAPSHOTLibrary') ... you think it would do something like (task ':app:prepareFlavor1ComTutelatechnologiesTkutilities01SNAPSHOTLibrary'), but it doesn't and you end up with a collision. argh. :(

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you do not want to use project references if you need to depend on a particular version. The project reference says basically what you mentioned in your question. More exactly it is not "I don't care which version" but rather something like "I depend on this subproject - in the version/state it is just now". This is what the project references are for - declaring a dependency on another **project**, not a particular JAR/version.

If you need to depend on a particular version, you should declare it without the project dependency, such as:

```
compile('com.mygroupid:submodule1:0.1-SNAPSHOT')
```

which is a shortened version of

```
compile(group:'com.mygroupid', name:'submodule1', version:'0.1-SNAPSHOT')
```

By default, this will use an artifact from a repo. But there is a solution that may bring you closer to what you want. The [eclipse-integration-gradle](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/wiki) plugin can detect such dependencies and *replace them* with project dependencies for Eclipse. The option is called "Remap Jars to Gradle Projects".

As a result, if there is a target project in your Eclipse workspace whose name corresponds to the target module, such Eclipse project will be used *instead* of the repo JAR.

I am not sure whether this is possible with multiple versions of the same project in the same workspace (if this is what you needed).

Comment: Well, the whole point of using gradle with android projects is moving away from eclipse, so the 2nd part is good to know, but ultimately not useful.  In terms of separating into completely different projects...I've considered it, but am likely just going to use properties or flavors to eventually control the build to flip between existing artifacts that have been built from the project or use the local-reference.

Comment: So what exactly is your desired setup? Do you want several versions of your project in separate workspace directories containing sources? And then allow cross-linking, such that when submodule SMA (represented as a gradle subproject ":prj:SMA") of version V2 depends on another submodule SMB (":prj:SMB") of version V1, then a) if there exists a workspace directory of project "prj" with declared version V1, then use that source directory, b) if there is no such workspace directory, then use the already-built JAR from some remote repository. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes, roughly.  Have you used the eclipse+maven integration before? basically how that works. where it auto-associates as needed.